# Attaching Large Libraries of Strings to an app

Tags: java, android, string, datastore, resourcebundle

I am very new to Java programming and I have a question about a project I am working on.

I need to, essentially, have a way to reference A string after the user has given me some input. This input will be through buttons i set up and this String will be about a paragraph long. I have been looking around the internet and I think what I need is to "Provide Resources" and "Access Resources" so that my code isn't filled with paragraphs of Strings.

I also have a fair amount of questions about how this works:

Is this more a question of Data and Storage? or both?

Do I have to go through ResourceBundling? What is that and where can i go so I can learn about it enough to be able to apply it?

Will I have to put all this data on the internet and have the app reference it through the web or can it somehow be downloaded with the app so the user can use it without having an internet connection? (It's a lot of data, I mean like a Lot)

I am more than willing to put in the time to learn this but I just need to be pointed in the right direction. A little insight on what to focus on, where to go to find it, or what keywords or concepts I should be looking for would be more help than you know.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: My best guess is: use an offline database. Focus on `SQLlite database CRUD operations` - Might also be of interest `providing a prefilled database from assets`

Comment: How much is a lot? One megabyte? Ten megabytes? More? (Many Android apps are several megabytes in size.)